# SQL database query wrapper

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

How can I write a better database query wrapper?

```
//code for connection 
exports.connect = function(callback) {
    client.connect(function(err, conInfo){
        if (err) callback(err);
        conInfo = "Connection at " + client.host + ":" + client.port + "/"
            + client.database + " used by " + client.user;
        callback(null, conInfo);
    });
};

//for queries that do not return realation
exports.runQuery = function(query_str, columns, params, callback) {
    var sqlQuery = query_str + " " + columns;
    client.query(sqlQuery, params, function(err) {
        console.log("NEW QUERY____________________");
        console.log(sqlQuery);
        console.log(params);
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(null);
    });
};

//for select queries
exports.executeQuery = function(query_str, callback) {
    var query = client.query(query_str, function(err){
        console.log("NEW QUERY____________________");
        console.log(query_str);
        if (err) throw err;
        query.on("row", function(row, result) {
            result.addRow(row);
        });
        query.on("end", function (result) {
            callback(null, result.rows);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do JS, even less `node.js`, but from the looks of it you seem to be taking in a `string` for your query, which means client code can do something like `"select x, y, sum(z) from mytable where x = " + someValue + " group by x, y"` - which is prone to SQL-injection: your client code needs to remember that.

If your `executeQuery` also took parameters, I think it would be clearer that when you need parameters, they should be passed as arguments to that function, not concatenated into the query string.